# Codeigniter: Check if array and execute a post

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to write data in two different db. I have some data that the user must insert but other data that the user could not insert.

For these data I should check if they are inserted, if the array is not empty I should insert these data in the db, otherwise not.

So my code is:

```
//this is the part that the user must insert.
     $meeting = [
                'motivation' => $this->post('motivation'),
                'date' => $this->post('date'),
                'start_at' => $this->post('start_at'),
                'end_at' => $this->post('end_at'),
            ];

            $meeting_id = $this->Meeting_model->post($meeting);
            var_dump($meeting);

//this is the part that user should not insert.
            $companions = [
            'name' => $this->post('name'),
            'surname' => $this->post('surname'),
            'fiscal_code' => $this->post('fiscal_code'),
            ];

//So there I should control if the array is empty.
            if(empty($companions))
            {
                var_dump($companions);
                foreach ($companions as $postCompanion) {
                    $dataCompanion = [
                            'name' => $postCompanion['name'],
                            'surname' => $postCompanion['surname'],
                            'fiscal_code' => $postCompanion['fiscal_code'],
                            'meeting_id' => $meeting_id,
                        ];
                    $companions_id = $this->Companion_model->post($dataCompanion);
                    $this->response(['companions_id', $companions_id]);
                }   
            }
```

My problem is that in this way, I never enter inside the "if", whether I pass the data or not.. I have tried before with: 
`$companions != []`

But if the user doesn't insert data they result like:

```
'name' => boolean false
'surname' => boolean false
'fiscal_code' => boolean false
```

And so I wrote my in the db like: VALUES (0, 0, 0)

How can I resolve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: this is a bit unclear, please explain *data that the user must insert but other data that the user could not insert*, what do you want to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: @Jack23 are you posting from any form..? if yes it should be $this->input->post instead of $this->post unless you are using a method named post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `$companions` is never empty, it already has keys. This should work for you- ↓↓

```
//this is the part that the user must insert.
     $meeting = [
                'motivation' => $this->post('motivation'),
                'date' => $this->post('date'),
                'start_at' => $this->post('start_at'),
                'end_at' => $this->post('end_at'),
            ];

            $meeting_id = $this->Meeting_model->post($meeting);
            var_dump($meeting);

//this is the part that user should not insert.
$companions = array();
if($this->post('name') != "" && $this->post('surname') != ""  && $this->post('surname') != ""){
                $companions = [
                'name' => $this->post('name'),
                'surname' => $this->post('surname'),
                'fiscal_code' => $this->post('fiscal_code'),
                ];
    }
    //So there I should control if the array is empty.
                if(empty($companions))
                {
                    var_dump($companions);
                    foreach ($companions as $postCompanion) {
                        $dataCompanion = [
                                'name' => $postCompanion['name'],
                                'surname' => $postCompanion['surname'],
                                'fiscal_code' => $postCompanion['fiscal_code'],
                                'meeting_id' => $meeting_id,
                            ];
                        $companions_id = $this->Companion_model->post($dataCompanion);
                        $this->response(['companions_id', $companions_id]);
                    }   
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

your variable `$companions` never been empty as array, because you already set the keys in it (with of course the value depends on the result of `$this->post()`).

If you have fixed 3 data `$this->post('name'), $this->post('surname'), $this->post('fiscal_code')`, you just check 3 of them, like this.

```
$companions = [
        'name' => $this->post('name'),
        'surname' => $this->post('surname'),
        'fiscal_code' => $this->post('fiscal_code'),
    ];

//So there I should control if the array is empty.
if(!empty($companions['name']) && !empty($companions['surname']) && !empty($companions['fiscal_code']))
{
    $companions['meeting_id'] = $meeting_id;
    $companions_id = $this->Companion_model->post($companions);
    $this->response(['companions_id', $companions_id]);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$companions isn't empty. Please see this code.

```
<?php


$companions = [
    'name' => NULL,
    'surname' => NULL,
    'fiscal_code' => NULL,
];


//DON'T IUSE THIS.

 if(empty($companions))
{    
     echo 'EMPTY :  ';
     var_dump($companions);
 }else{
     echo 'NOT EMPTY :  ';
     var_dump($companions);
 }

// USE THIS.

if(empty($companions['name']) && empty($companions['surname']) && empty($companions['fiscal_code'])){

     echo 'EMPTY :  ';
     die(var_dump($companions));

}else{
    echo 'NOT EMPTY :  ';
     die(var_dump($companions));
}
```